# Third-Party Javascript/Typescript Loggers That Allow External Configuration

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Currently, my Angular application uses NGX-Logger for console logging. This is nice in that it allows different logging levels. Unfortunately, it forces me to set a logging level across the application in my app.module.ts.

In the java world, I can configure my loggers externally. For example, in Spring Boot, I can add this line to application.properties:

```
logging.level.com.package.myclass=WARN
```

Are there any Javascript/Typescript logging libraries that would allow me to configure logging externally, and set a default (root) level?

Comment: You might want to look at [winston](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston)